# Extract HTML data from HTML code in PHP

Tags: php, web-scraping

I want to to extract some data from a page.

The data thats I need is in text between HTML tags here on these lines :

```
<div class="tgme_page_title">تست</div>    
<div class="tgme_page_extra">4 members</div>
<a class="tgme_action_button_new" href="tg://join?invite=GYJezj_NevMyTZP5KchgPA">
    Join Group
</a>
```

I want extract data and stored in variable like this:

```
$data1 = "تست"  
$data2 = "4 members"   
$data3 = "Join Group"
```

How can I do this?

Thanks for your time

Comment: $html = '<div class="tgme_page_title">بنردهی ویکی گپ</div>    <div class="tgme_page_extra">4 members</div>
<a class="tgme_action_button_new" href="tg://join?invite=GYJezj_NevMyTZP5KchgPA">Join Group</a>   ';
echo strip_tags($html);

Comment: You need to use `curl()` function to retrieve data from URL.

Comment: please explane how I do this. I'm new to php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HTML DOM parser.

Example of code to find a div with class and extract his value, I didn't try:

```
$html = '<div class="tgme_page_title">تست</div><div class="tgme_page_extra">4 members</div><a class="tgme_action_button_new" href="tg://join?invite=GYJezj_NevMyTZP5KchgPA">Join Group</a>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);

$classname = "tgme_page_title";
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");
$data1 = $nodes{0}->nodeValue;

$classname = "tgme_page_extra";
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");
$data2 = $nodes{0}->nodeValue;

$classname = "tgme_action_button_new";
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");
$data3 = $nodes{0}->nodeValue;
```

Here is the documentation : http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: thats return null

Comment: Well see documentation, in some case it's not "textContent" but there is a good function to extract text between tags.

Comment: and what about ->nodeValue ?

Comment: nothing again  
     
 
thats return null

Comment: try whit this. It's working for me.

Comment: [Meloman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2282880/meloman) you are great. thats work. thanks very very very much and good luck